# UPDATING a table based on a FROM clause, how do I limit with WHERE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL UPDATE clause which looks like:

```
UPDATE table 
SET column =value
FROM
(SELECT bla bla FROM bla bla WHERE col = val)
JOIN
(SELECT bla bla FROM bla bla WHERE col = val)
```

I want to limit the UPDATE to WHERE a particular column is equal to a particular value.

It doesnt appear to be legal to insert the WHERE after the JOIN or after the SET? I thought I had already limited the update using the JOIN but it doesn't appear so.

Where can I insert my WHERE clause?

Comment: possible duplicate see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836126/update-with-join-statement-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `vlaue` is a literal value, not a value coming form either of these joined tables, then you can do this:

```
UPDATE table t1
SET t1.column = value -- literalvalue
FROM
(
   SELECT bla bla FROM bla bla)
   JOIN
   (
      SELECT bla bla FROM bla bla
   ) on thefirstblah = somethingfromthesecondblah
) t1
```

**Or:**

```
UPDATE table t1
SET t1.column = value -- literalvalue
FROM
(
   SELECT bla bla FROM bla bla
   JOIN anotherbla ON ----
) t1;
```

However, if this `value` is coming from one of the joined table:

```
UPDATE table t1
SET t1.column = t2.value 
FROM table t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON ---
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example has been stripped down so far that it's hard to tell exactly what you are after.

It might just be a matter of giving your nested selects aliases like so:

```
Update table 
  Set column =value
From
  (Select bla bla From bla bla Where col = val) a
    Join
  (Select bla bla From bla bla Where col = val) b
    On a.blah = b.blah -- did this go missing from the example?
Where
  ...
```

SQL Server has an update form that may help:

```
Update
  t1
Set
  blah
From
  table1 t1 -- note same as updated table
    inner join
  (select...) a
    On t1.blah = a.blah
Where
  t1.Col = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use query something like this :

Important thing that worked for me was join before update after.

```
update table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id2 set t1.value = t2.otherValue;
```