# update one table with data from another

Tags: sql, database

Table 1:

```
id    name    desc
-----------------------
1     a       abc
2     b       def
3     c       adf
```

Table 2:

```
id    name    desc
-----------------------
1     x       123
2     y       345
```

How do I run an **sql update** query that can update Table 1 with Table 2's name and desc using the same id? So the end result I would get is

Table 1:

```
id    name    desc
-----------------------
1     x       123
2     y       345
3     c       adf
```

How can this be done for:

- SQL Server
- MySQL
- PostgreSQL
- Oracle

Answer (score 91, accepted):

For MySql:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.id
SET table1.name = table2.name,
    table1.`desc` = table2.`desc`
```

For Sql Server:

```
UPDATE   table1
SET table1.name = table2.name,
    table1.[desc] = table2.[desc]
FROM table1 JOIN table2 
   ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: +1. In SQL Server I usually use the same structured update as the one you've shown. But in this particular case the `FROM` part could be a bit simpler: just `FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id`, and the aliases on the left side of each assignment could be dropped.

Comment: @andriy-m i prefer putting the join predicate in the `JOIN` and not in the `WHERE`...

Comment: Can you update for Oracle, perhaps? Maybe confirm either of those 2 statements would work for Oracle?

Comment: @p-campbell See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join

Comment: I'll like to add: for Postgresql, the syntax is slightly different

`update a set field1 = concat_ws(' ',field1, table2.middle_name, table2.first_name) from table2 where a.id = table2.fieldX;`

Just added some funtions to show what is possible.

Answer (score 27):

Oracle 11g R2:

```
create table table1 (
  id number,
  name varchar2(10),
  desc_ varchar2(10)
);

create table table2 (
  id number,
  name varchar2(10),
  desc_ varchar2(10)
);

insert into table1 values(1, 'a', 'abc');
insert into table1 values(2, 'b', 'def');
insert into table1 values(3, 'c', 'ghi');

insert into table2 values(1, 'x', '123');
insert into table2 values(2, 'y', '456');

merge into table1 t1
using (select * from table2) t2
on (t1.id = t2.id)
when matched then update set t1.name = t2.name, t1.desc_ = t2.desc_;

select * from table1;

        ID NAME       DESC_
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 x          123
         2 y          456
         3 c          ghi
```

See also [Oracle - Update statement with inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2446764).

Answer (score 9):

```
UPDATE table1
SET 
`ID` = (SELECT table2.id FROM table2 WHERE table1.`name`=table2.`name`)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try following code. It is working for me....

```
UPDATE TableOne 
SET 
field1 =(SELECT TableTwo.field1 FROM TableTwo WHERE TableOne.id=TableTwo.id),
field2 =(SELECT TableTwo.field2 FROM TableTwo WHERE TableOne.id=TableTwo.id)
WHERE TableOne.id = (SELECT  TableTwo.id 
                             FROM   TableTwo 
                             WHERE  TableOne.id = TableTwo.id)
```

Comment: this query is slow to process.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following block of query to update Table1 with Table2 based on ID:

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2 
SET Table1.DataColumn= Table2.DataColumn
where Table1.ID= Table2.ID;
```

This is the easiest and fastest way to tackle this problem.