# How to update one table with data from another table in a separate database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [update one table with data from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036918/update-one-table-with-data-from-another)

Extreme SQL noob here. I have two databases (Database1, Database2). Each db has the same tables. I want to update TableA in Database2 with the data in TableA from Database1 (Database1,TableA -> Database2,TableA).

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MS SQL, Oracle, MySQL)? Do you want to completely overwrite the destination table with the source table? Just add new rows?

Comment: This is in MS SQL. Basically the destination table contains much of the same data as the source table, but the source table may have different values in existing rows and/or have new rows. I want the destination table to match the source table, so I may have to insert new rows if they do not exist in the destination table, and also update existing rows.

Comment: How often do you need to sync the 2 tables? Are you looking for real-time or something on a daily basis?

Comment: This will probably just be a one-time update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, assuming you use a `dbo` schema.

```
insert into Database2.dbo.TableA (column1, column2, etc)
select column1, column2, etc
from Database1.dbo.TableA
```

You might want to `truncate Database2.dbo.TableA` first if the incoming data should overwrite the old or you are using an identity field.

If you need the ids to be the exact same across the tables, you should disable the identity property on `Database2.dbo.Table` before running the script and re-enable it afterward.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this as a one-time data sync, SQL Server offers an Import/Export Data under the Tasks option when you right-click on a particular database. You can select the sql server/database/tables to be used as a data source and destination and then run the job. When you set this up, there will be an opportunity to set an option to clear the destination table and insert all the data from the source.

You can also schedule these types of transactions to be run on a scheduled basis, though I have never done much work in this area.

Comment: Tried the Import/Export method but it failed on the copy process. The error message was very cryptic and not very useful. Is there a way to script this? I also tried Justin's solution above but it failed to insert do to duplicate keys. I just want to insert new rows/keys and update existing ones if they are different.

Comment: Can you post the error message? You could use Justin's approach if you clear all the records from your destination table first. That should avoid the duplicate keys.  To clear your records, I have used truncate table which worked more efficiently for me.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try "truncate" and then try running Justin's approach.

Comment: Here is the error message (there was lots more, but here is the gist): `"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SharedContent_sharedContentGuid'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SharedContent'.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)`. Guess I just need to clear the destination table first. :-)

Comment: Looks like both problems are related to clearing out the old data to avoid duplicate keys.

Comment: Tried to truncate like so: `TRUNCATE TABLE tablename`. Got the following error message: `Cannot truncate table because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.`

Comment: I have never ran into the problem with the Foreign key constraint because of the nature of the tables I did the data transfers on. You might be able to disable the foreign key constraint temporarily to do this data transfer. I would assume you will want to do a data transfer for each table involved in the foreign key constraint to keep your db structure working correctly.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct about disabling the foreign key constraint. More info is found here about this issue: http://forums.asp.net/t/1283840.aspx/1