# Update table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table variable `@searchResult`:

```
DECLARE @searchResult TABLE (
    [name_template] NVARCHAR(50),
    [record_id] INT,
    [record_name] NVARCHAR(50)
);
```

And table `[records]`:

```
CREATE TABLE [records] (
    [record_id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [record_name] NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

`@searchResult` contains records with `[name_template]` filled only. I want to update it with latest `[record_id]` and `[record_name]` from `[records]` table that match `[name_template]`.

I've tried folowing SQL query with no success:

```
UPDATE @searchResult
SET [record_id] = r.[record_id], [record_name] = r.[record_name]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1
          r.[record_id]
        , r.[record_name]
    FROM [records] AS r
    WHERE r.[record_name] LIKE [name_template]
    ORDER BY r.[record_id] DESC
) AS r;
```

Error message:

> Invalid column name 'name_template'.

What is correct syntax to update `@searchResult` with desired values?

Comment: Look at your query being used for an update. I assume the table records does not have a column named name_template? It is is your table variable. Remember your query has to execute on its own. That means in this case you have to join to your table variable in the query.

Comment: quotes missing  ..like 'name_template' or like '%name_template%'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update one table with data from another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036918/update-one-table-with-data-from-another)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do a `CROSS APPLY` on the tables.

```
UPDATE @searchResult
SET [record_id] = r.[record_id], 
    [record_name] = r.[record_name]
FROM @searchResult SR
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM [records]
    WHERE [record_name] LIKE [name_template]   -- Your wish, but do you really need LIKE matching??
    ORDER BY [record_id] DESC
) AS r;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t
SET [record_id] = r.[record_id], 
    [record_name] = r.[record_name]
FROM @searchResult t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX([record_id]) As [record_id]
            ,[record_name]
    FROM [records]
    GROUP BY [record_name] 
) r
ON r.[record_name] LIKE t.[name_template];
```

**Update:**
Seems to be working fine from what I've tested:

Create table and table variable:

```
CREATE TABLE [records] (
    [record_id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [record_name] NVARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @searchResult TABLE (
    [name_template] NVARCHAR(50),
    [record_id] INT,
    [record_name] NVARCHAR(50)
);
```

Populate with sample data:

```
INSERT INTO [records] ([record_name]) VALUES('a'), ('a'), ('a'), ('b'), ('b')

INSERT INTO @searchResult ([name_template]) VALUES ('a'), ('b')
```

Update table variable:

```
UPDATE t
SET [record_id] = r.[record_id], 
    [record_name] = r.[record_name]
FROM @searchResult t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX([record_id]) As [record_id]
            ,[record_name]
    FROM [records]
    GROUP BY [record_name] 
) r
ON r.[record_name] LIKE t.[name_template];
```

Check results:

```
SELECT *
FROM records

SELECT *
FROM @searchResult

DROP TABLE records
```

Results:

```
records
record_id   record_name
----------- -----------
1           a
2           a
3           a
4           b
5           b

@searchResult
name_template   record_id   record_name
-------------   ---------   -----------
a               3           a
b               5           b
```

Comment: This query works, but it updates [record_id] and [record_name] not with latest data.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Here is sample when it failes to updated with latest data (keep your test data and add this one):
`INSERT INTO [records] ([record_name]) VALUES('ab');
INSERT INTO @searchResult ([name_template]) VALUES ('a%')`
I expect @searchResult for [name_template] 'a%' after update statement to contain [record_id] of 'ab'

Comment: For this you will need a dynamic sql solution. Sql server will not treat the `%` inside the table variable as a wildcard, it will treat it as a part of the string. However, there are ways around that, if you can change the table variable.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is special setting responsible for that, but in my case `%` in table variable is treated as I expect it to be (match any amount of characters)

Comment: well, seems like it's my mistake. At least you got an answer to your question., and a lesson of the importance of sample data...