# Insert into sql 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have 2 tables.

table 1: **old**

```
id mod1 mod2 exp
----------------
1  280  20   1
```

table 2: **new**

```
id mod1 mod2 exp
----------------
1  0    0    0
```

And i want to fill the second table with all mod1 mod2 exp where die id is the same like in 1.

In table 1 i have some more ids as in table 2.

query tried so far.

```
UPDATE table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.entry = table2.entry
SET table1.mod1 = table2.mod1;
```

Comment: read about update ... join ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update one table with data from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036918/update-one-table-with-data-from-another)

Answer (score 0):

You are close.

The correct query is below.

```
UPDATE new t1
INNER JOIN old t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.mod1 = t2.mod1
    ,t1.mod2 = t2.mod2
    ,t1.exp = t2.exp;

COMMIT;
```

You can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/WZGD71212)**