# update one table with data from another using derived key value

Tags: sql, oracle

Table 1:

```
id    name    desc
------------------
1     a       abc
2     b       def
3     c       adf


Table 2:
name    desc
------------
x       123
y       345
```

How do I run an sql update query that can update Table 1 with Table 2's name and desc using the id of table 1 and rownum in table2? It's okay to assume that rownum in table2 is the same as id of table 1. So the end result I would get is

```
Table 1:

id    name    desc
------------------
1     x       123
2     y       345
3     c       adf
```

Below are scripts for table creation and record insertion

```
create table table1 (
  id number,
  name varchar2(10),
 desc_ varchar2(10)
);

create table table2 (
  name varchar2(10),
  desc_ varchar2(10)
);

insert into table1 values(1, 'a', 'abc');
insert into table1 values(2, 'b', 'def');
insert into table1 values(3, 'c', 'ghi');

insert into table2 values( 'x', '123');
insert into table2 values( 'y', '456');
```

Credits to "[update one table with data from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036918/update-one-table-with-data-from-another)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "rownum" in a table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no ordering without an ordering column.

Oracle does provide `rowid` as a built-in column identifier.  This is not the same as `rownum` and is not guaranteed to be in order.

You *can* use `rownum`, but the value is not guarantee to have any particular meaning and might change between runs:

```
update table1
    set (name, desc) = (select name, desc
                        from (select t2.*, rownum as seqnum
                              from table2 
                             ) t2
                        where seqnum = table1.id
                       )
    where id <= (select count(*) from table2);
```

Comment: Can you explain why you have the where clause  `"where id <= (select count(*) from table2)"` Thanks

Comment: @user2008558 . . . The tables have different numbers of rows.  You only want to update the "first" <n> rows where <n> is the number of rows in `table2`.