# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row update...?? Help?

Tags: sql

My Query returns this error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row update, This is my query

```
Update Table_b B
Set B.Material_Desc = (Select A.Material_Desc From Table_a A Where A.PartNo = B.PartNo)
```

I have two different tables : `Table_a` and `Table_b`, both have same columns `PartNo` and `Material_Desc`. I want the `Material_Desc` in `Table_b` to update the `Material_Desc` in `Table_a` when `PartNo` are equals.

The above query returns the ORA-01427 error, Please can anyone correct my query ?

Comment: you should provide the name of the database server you're using. Depending on it, better answer can be provided !

Comment: Given the error number, I'd say this is Oracle. (Better tagging would still have been nice, though.)

Comment: If this is Oracle, my answer won't work at all... You can have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join

Comment: MERGE
INTO    Table_b
USING   (
        SELECT  t1.rowid AS rid, t2.Material_Desc
        FROM    Table_b t1
        JOIN    Table_a t2
        ON      Table_b.PartNo = Table_a.PartNo
        
        )
ON      rowid = rid
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET    Table_a.Material_Desc  = Table_b.Material_Desc, I just got this query from above link, This is giving me  ORA-00969: missing ON keyword error, Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your subquery is returning a whole bunch of rows where you should have only one. You can't do this like this.

Depending on the SQL database you're using, something like this should work better :

```
UPDATE Table_b B
SET B.Materiel_Desc = A.Materiel_Desc
INNER JOIN Table_a A ON A.PartNo = B.PartNo
```

It is possible you must adapt the syntax to your database. For example, I think you cannot do it like this with MySQL. According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html you should do :

```
UPDATE Table_b, Table_A
SET Table_b.Materiel_Desc = Table_A.Materiel_Desc
WHERE Table_b.PartNo = Table_a.PartNo;
```

Comment: Like said in my comment to your question, if you're using Oracle, this won't work, better follow the link I provided.