# SQL ORACLE ORA-00969: missing ON keyword?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two different tables : Table_a and Table_b, both have same columns PartNo and Material_Desc. I want the Material_Desc in Table_b to update the Material_Desc in Table_a when PartNo are equals. This is my query

```
MERGE INTO Table_b 
USING ( SELECT t1.rowid AS rid
               , t2.Material_Desc
        FROM Table_b t1 
           JOIN Table_a t2 
           ON Table_b.PartNo = Table_a.PartNo ) 
ON rowid = rid 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE 
    SET Table_a.Material_Desc = Table_b.Material_Desc;
```

I know Oracle doesn't support joins for update statement  so I tried the above query. Still it gives me ORACLE ORA-00969: missing ON keyword error

Comment: See my comment on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2446859/244826

Comment: The condition after the `ON ` **must** be in brackets: `ON (rowid = rid)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might put "(" and ")". So write :

ON **(** rowid = rid **)**

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the syntax problem: when you merge using a subquery, you have to alias it to something. But more importantly, you don't need to use a subquery.

```
MERGE INTO Table_a USING Table_b ON (Table_a.PartNo = Table_b.PartNo) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Table_a.Material_Desc = Table_b.Material_Desc
```

First of all, you have to put the table you want to update into the `INTO` portion. Second, doing the join in a subselect and merging on rowids won't offer you any benefit that I can think of.

Comment: am getting ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables error for the above query

Comment: Maybe this helps to understand ORA-30926: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=257751  see the last comment.

Comment: sorry I didn't get it from the last comment of the above link.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps not as efficient as a merge statment, but should do the work:

```
update table_b tb
set tb.Material_Desc = (select ta.Material_Desc 
                        from   table_a ta 
                        where  ta.PartNo = tb.PartNo
                        and    rownum = 1
                       )
where tb.rowid in (
                  SELECT t1.rowid                       
                    FROM Table_b t1 
                        , Table_a t2 
                    WHERE  t1.PartNo = t2.PartNo
                   )
```

Comment: This query gives ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row error.

Comment: @sailaja: I have assumed that partno is unique. I've adjusted my answer, so only the first found entry is taken

Comment: No,each Part_No has multiple values like for ex.001A has 100 items and 001B has 50 items with unique Serial_No, but the Description is same, so I have another table(table_a) which holds only PartNo & Material_Desc, I want to update all the desc for these PartNo's from this table_a