# PL/SQL: UPDATE query with multiple matches in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

TABLE_A:

```
ID      TYPE    DATE_UPLOADED   EXPIRED
9872    APPLE   03-JAN-11       0
9874    MANGO   03-JAN-11       0
9873    GRAPE   03-JAN-11       0
```

TABLE_B:

```
TYPE    LIFE
APPLE   3
MANGO   2
GRAPE   1
```

What I would like to achieve here is to update the `EXPIRED`
field of `TABLE_A` to a value of `1` when it's `DATE_UPLOADED`
has exceeded it's `LIFE` for that type as of the current date.

This update query is where I'm currently stuck with. I know its
wrong, that's where I need your help.

Update query:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET EXPIRED = 1
WHERE EXPIRED = 0
AND (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(DATE_UPLOADED)) >
(
    SELECT LIFE
    FROM TABLE_B 
);
```

Do note that the `TYPE` field may be anything and may be more
than what is given in the sample data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Different problem but 'could' use the same solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not linking the two tables. Try something like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET EXPIRED = 1
WHERE EXPIRED = 0
AND (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(DATE_UPLOADED)) >
(
    SELECT LIFE
    FROM TABLE_B 
    WHERE TYPE = TABLE_A.TYPE
);
```

Comment: That's not valid SQL for Oracle

Comment: Good point. And it's not valid ANSI SQL either I believe. Edited.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to use some aggregate in the subquery in order to ensure that only a single row is returned. Otherwise it might fail with an "single row query returned more than one row" error

Comment: The question refers to LIFE in the singular for a particular TYPE, so my assumption was this would not be needed in this context. In general terms, yes, I agree.

Comment: Thanks for this one! Saved me a lot of headache.