# Insert by select statement -oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, oracle11g

I was just trying to copy the values of one column into an empty column of another table .
The two tables are `students` and `payments` . 
**Students** have two columns :

- rno -  primary key of number type               `// i filled it with some entries`
- amount                                                           `//this is completely empty`

**payments**  also have same no of columns :

- rno -   foreign key referencing rno of students table
- amount        `//this is FILLED`

Now to copy `amounts` column *from payments to students ,* i tried this command

`insert into students(amount) select amount from payments ;`

now normally this command works like a charm ,but here it is behaving slightly different . It throws an error that 
`NULL values cannot be inserted into students.rno`

I tried reasoning that maybe its due to different number of entries inserted in two tables , but on eqalizing the no . of entries in  both the tables , just the same result .

So the question is  that **how can i copy**  in such a situation ?

Comment: Did you mean to insert just amounts or did you want a `rno` there so that the data is meaningful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite clear on your requirements, but this will populate the STUDENTS table with the SUM of matching payments in the PAYMENTS table.  Is this what you're after?

```
UPDATE STUDENTS
SET    AMOUNT = (SELECT SUM(PAYMENTS.AMOUNTS)
                 FROM   PAYMENTS
                 WHERE  PAYMENTS.RNO = STUDENTS.RNO);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to add records to the students table (which is what `INSERT` does) you want to `UPDATE` existing records.

I am not very familiar with Oracle syntax, but I adapted the answer to this question [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join) to hopefully meet your needs.

```
UPDATE students
SET    students.amount = (SELECT payments.amount
                          FROM   payments
                          WHERE  students.rno = payments.rno)
```

Comment: Note that this will error if more than 1 payment for a student.

Comment: Oh, good point. I assumed the relationship was 1:1 for some reason. P.S., Thanks for the edit, I noticed afterword it was rno not mo ;)

Comment: @cagcowboy Also, that's interesting that this would throw an error. If I'm not mistaken, in SQL Server the "last" match would be the value that is used in the UPDATE. I like Oracle's take on this better.