# UPDATE-SET query by joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have 3 tables, say `RELATIONS,PERSON,COMPANY`
I need to `UPDATE` `active_flag` field of `PERSON` to `'I'/'A'` by joining these 3 tables.
My requirement is like

```
UPDATE PERSON p
SET p.active_flag ='I'
FROM PERSON p,RELATIONS r,COMPANY c
WHERE p.email ='email@gmail.com'
AND c.rel_id = r.id
AND r.dep_id = '1234567'
AND r.book_id = '1234567'
```

How can I do that??

Comment: please mention the relation between PERSON and RElation or Persion and COMPANY table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle - Update statement with inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)

Comment: Your query is also (probably) incorrect. It contains a Cartesian join between `person` and `relations` and `company`... you probably want to join these together somehow?

Answer (score 1):

--Not sure about joins

```
UPDATE p
SET 
    p.[active_flag] ='I'
FROM Person p
    INNER JOIN Relations r ON
        r.[vNumber] = p.[vesionNo]
    INNER JOIN Company c ON
        c.[rel_id] = r.[id]
WHERE
    p.[email] ='email@gmail.com'
AND r.[dep_id] = '1234567' 
AND r.[book_id] = '1234567'
```

Comment: Sorry but this is incorrect. It's SQL-Server syntax _not_ Oracle. Also you cannot do updates with joins in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

```
merge into person p
using (
       select id
       FROM PERSON p,RELATIONS r,COMPANY c
       WHERE p.email ='email@gmail.com'
             AND c.rel_id = r.id
             AND r.dep_id = '1234567'
             AND r.book_id = '1234567'
      ) pu
on (pu.id = p.id)
when matched then update set p.active_flag ='I'
```