# How to update one table column with its own value plus a variable from other table?

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle - Update statement with inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)

In SQL Server Developer Edition, I want to update a column with its own value and variable from another table.

In table `sa_tran_item`, `ref_no6` field is showing `"NYN"`
and other table `apo_rms_i_item_place`, `SORTIMENTSGRUPP_KOD` field showing 10

I want to update table `sa_tran_item`, `ref_no6` field as `"NYN10"`

**My query**

```
UPDATE sa_tran_item 
SET ref_no6 = "ref_no6" + "a.SORTIMENTSGRUPP_KOD" 
FROM apo_rms_i_item_place a, sa_tran_item 
WHERE a.varnummer in  (select item from item_master where item_number_type='MANL' and PRIMARY_REF_ITEM_IND = 'Y' and item_parent in 
(select  ITEM from sa_tran_item where  error_ind = 'Y' and tran_seq_no in 
(select tran_seq_no from sa_error where tran_seq_in ='49910349001'  error_code like 'ACG_NOT_FOUND') ));
```

Comment: whats the datatype of column `SORTIMENTSGRUPP_KOD`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oralce the double pipe `||` is used to concatenate string values. You can update using

```
SET ref_no6 = ref_no6 || TO_CHAR(a.SORTIMENTSGRUPP_KOD)
```

if column `SORTIMENTSGRUPP_KOD` is integer type and

```
SET ref_no6 = ref_no6 || a.SORTIMENTSGRUPP_KOD
```

if it's of type string/varchar2.

Comment: Ok. I updated the statement.. buts still error is SQL Error: ORA-00921: unexpected end of SQL command

Comment: my sql now was 
UPDATE sa_tran_item 
SET ref_no6 = ref_no6||(select TO_CHAR (SORTIMENTSGRUPP_KOD)
FROM apo_rms_i_item_place 
WHERE varnummer in  (select item from item_master where item_number_type='MANL' and PRIMARY_REF_ITEM_IND = 'Y' and item_parent in 
(select  ITEM from sa_tran_item where  error_ind = 'Y' and tran_seq_no in 
(select tran_seq_no from sa_error where tran_seq_in ='49910349001' and  error_code like 'ACG_NOT_FOUND') ));

Comment: datatype SORTIMENTSGRUPP_KOD              NUMBER

Comment: okay... I think your query is not supported in oracle. U need `MERGE` in oracle to do inner join update like in `MS SQL`. Please refer the link for syntax. http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html