# "SQL command not properly ended" error from UPDATE query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update multiple rows in a SQL Server table in VB.NET code.  However, I am focusing on updating one row before I include more `SELECT` statements.  I understand the following method is very flexible, but it is throwing the error "SQL command not properly ended":

```
UPDATE ndcs 
SET    PACKAGE_TYPE_CODE = x.package_type_code, 
       PACKAGE_DESC = x.package_desc, 
       COMMENTS = x.comments 
FROM   hub_non_dcs_product_pkgtype ndcs 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT PRODUCT_ID = 'SEN0982_pdf_1', 
                          PACKAGE_TYPE_CODE = '', 
                          PACKAGE_DESC = '', 
                          COMMENTS = 'DPDC LITERATURE') x 
               ON x.product_id = ndcs.product_id
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: To be honest I can't see anything wrong with that - I ran it through SQL 2008 and it worked fine.  Have you tried what I call the 'just in case stupid factor' changes, like `'SEN0982_pdf_1' AS PRODUCT_ID...`.  Or even, strip it right back and try with a `WHERE` clause from the off?

Comment: Do you have the full error message to post? I'm not finding any immediate syntax errors either.

Comment: Your error message appears to be an Oracle error, are you sure this is SQL Server? What happens if you put a semi-colon at the end of your query? Can you show the VB.NET code that executes the SQL code? And as others have said, the full error message/stack trace would be useful.

Comment: As @Pondlife suggests, are you sure this query is run against SQL-Server and not Oracle?

Comment: Assuming it is Oracle, it's probably [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)

Comment: I've been bouncing between Oracle and SQL Server all day.  This is Oracle SQL.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE ndcs 
SET (PACKAGE_TYPE_CODE, PACKAGE_DESC, COMMENTS )  = (
SELECT
    x.package_type_code, 
    x.package_desc, 
    x.comments 
FROM   
    hub_non_dcs_product_pkgtype ndcs 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT PRODUCT_ID = 'SEN0982_pdf_1', 
                      PACKAGE_TYPE_CODE = '', 
                      PACKAGE_DESC = '', 
                      COMMENTS = 'DPDC LITERATURE') x 
           ON x.product_id = ndcs.product_id 
)
```