# UPDATE statement with SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an UPDATE statement with SELECT statement in ORACLE but I kept getting "invalid identifier" error. I am sure that the field exists.

This is my SQL:

```
update 
(
select distinct a.item_id, a.account_code, b.item_id, b.account_code
from bp.poline a, mt.material b 
where a.item_id = b.item_id  
and a.account_code is not null and b.account_code is null
)
set b.account_code = a.account_code
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "A"."ACCOUNT_CODE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier
```

Comment: Doesn't it imply that `account_code` is not a field in your alias `a` ?

Comment: account_code exists in a. I had checked that.

Comment: See this related question: [Oracle - Update statement with inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2446764/851811).

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle you can update a subquery only if Oracle is able to locate precisely **one and only one row** of a base table for each row of the subquery. Furthermore, [additional restrictions apply](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF55455) concerning the use of analytics function, aggregates, etc.

In your example the `DISTINCT` will make Oracle unable to update the subquery because **one** row of the subquery could point to **several** rows of the base table.

If you remove the `DISTINCT`, the query will work only if there is a unique index on `MATERIAL(item_id)` so that each row in the table `POLINE` can only be associated with at most one row in `MATERIAL`:

```
UPDATE (SELECT a.item_id, a.account_code acct_a, 
               b.item_id, b.account_code acct_b
          FROM bp.poline a, mt.material b
         WHERE a.item_id = b.item_id
           AND a.account_code IS NOT NULL
           AND b.account_code IS NULL)
   SET acct_a = acct_b
```

---

Updating a join is very efficient but has several restrictions, what if you don't have this index?

You could write a standard update with a different subquery:

```
UPDATE poline a
   SET a.account_code = (SELECT b.account_code
                           FROM material b
                          WHERE b.item_id = a.item_id
                            AND b.account_code is not null)
 WHERE a.account_code IS NULL
   AND a.item_id IN (SELECT b.item_id 
                       FROM material b
                      WHERE b.account_code IS NOT NULL)
```

The most elegant solution IMO however, inspired by an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2446859/119634), would be:

```
MERGE INTO (SELECT * FROM a WHERE account_code IS NULL) a
     USING (SELECT * FROM b WHERE account_code IS NOT NULL) b
        ON (a.item_id = b.item_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.account_code = b.account_code;
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried to remove the DISTINCT syntax, but I am still getting the same invalid identifier error.

I am not able to create unique index on the table. So is there any way that I can write the query?

Comment: @cooldude: this is not the only thing I changed, look more closely :)

Comment: You mean the alias too? I had included the alias and removed the distinct.

Comment: If it's helpful to you guys here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd015/1).

Comment: @VincentMalgrat, I saw my mistake. I should just use the alias at the SET commands. I had changed that and I am no longer getting the invalid identifier error, but I am getting a different error now, which is:

'Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.'

Comment: See my updated answer, you can use a standard update with a subquery ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f097a/1)). @xavi thanks for the SQLFiddle !

Answer (score 0):

to use **update** statement with **select** statement in **SQL** below is the syntax...and its working in my code
in this i am using derived table
may be this vl help you

for ex....

**UPDATE** SHIFT_MST SET SHIFT_MST.SHIFT_DESC=A.SHIFT_DESC,SHIFT_MST.SHIFT_CODE=A.SHIFT_CODE **from**

(**SELECT** * FROM TEMP_SHIFT_MST)a

where a.SHIFT_ID=SHIFT_MST.SHIFT_ID

Comment: CHECK THIS LINK IT WILL HELP YOU  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/how-to-update-a-table-from-a-another-table