# SQL to update a table based on information in 2 other tables

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have 3 tables that I am currently working with. `USER`, `WORKSTATION` and `USER_WORKSTATION` (basically a temp table).

My

`USER` table consists of `user_id` and `user_name`,

`WORKSTATION` consists of `workstation_id`, `workstation_name` and `user_id`.

As of right now, the `user_id` column is empty for all workstations and that is my problem.

I have created a table (imported from excel) `USER_WORKSTATION`. It consists of only `user_name`s and their corresponding workstation(s). Is there someway that I can write an update query that will update the `WORKSTATION` table with the `user_id` found in the `USER` table based on the `user_name` and `workstation_name` combination in the `USER_WORKSTATION` table? I do not have any constraints currently set up and I'm using Oracle.

Comment: @N West I have been trying JOINs but have been coming up empty. update workstation (select lic_user.user_name FROM lic_user JOIN lic_combo ON lic_user.user_name = lic_combo.user_name) set workstation.user_id = lic_user.user_id;

Comment: Sorry, forgot that you have to use a slightly different syntax in oracle. Answer in a minute :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MERGE statement for this:

```
MERGE
INTO    WORKSTATION W1
USING   (SELECT W2.rowid AS rid, U.user_id
           FROM USER_WORKSTATION UW
           JOIN USER U
             ON UW.user_name = U.user_name
           JOIN WORKSTATION W2
             ON UW.workstation_name = W2.workstation_name
        ) q
ON      (W1.rowid = q.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET W1.user_id = q.user_id;
```

You can do an `UPDATE` as well, it's a little messier.

See [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)

Comment: I appreciate your quick assistance @N West but I'm afraid that answer has confused me more. Why the letter abbreviations?

Comment: That's just adding an alias to the tables for ease of use. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp .

Comment: Essentially, the MERGE statement takes the Resultset in the USING clause, joins it to the table in the INTO clause, and the `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` tells the database to update rows that match with the defined `SET` operation.

Comment: @N West: Im receiving this error: ORA-00904: "UW"."WORKSTATION_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: Does USER_WORKSTATION not have workstation id in it? Maybe change the join to join on workstation_name??

Comment: I just noticied that and made the right change. But then immediately got this error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: Then likely your workstation name / user names aren't unique on the tables. You need to have a unique set. Take a look at this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4181ab compared to this one with a workstation who has 2 users: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/418fe/1

Comment: Thank you for all of your assistance on this issue. To not waste anymore of my time I merged what I had in excel and just imported into Oracle. An easy fix this time for what should should have been a simple SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this plsql block.
   I Suppose one user one workstation.

```
Declare
user_id User.userid%type;
ws_name WorkStationUser.wsname%type;
Cursor WSUSER is select * from WorkStationUser;
user_name WorkStationUser.username%type;

Begin

Open WSUSER;


Loop
 Fetch WSUSER into user_name, ws_name;
 select userid into user_id from USER where username=user_name;
 select wsname into ws_name from WORKSTATIONUSER where username=user_name;
 update WORKSTATION set userid=user_id whrer wsname=ws_name;
 EXIT WHEN WSUSER%notfound;
END LOOP;
close WSUSER;
END;
```

Comment: Please don't use cursors if a simple SQL statement works!!! Set-based processing is what RDBMS's do best!