# UPDATE multiple field values based on JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

```
UPDATE table1
SET
table1.field1 = table2.field1,
table1.field2 = table2.field2,
table1.field3 = table2.field3,
table1.fieldn = table2.fieldn
JOIN
table1 ON table2.joinfield = table1.joinfield
```

I'm getting error in Oracle (Toad for Oracle):  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: You can't update on a JOIN in Oracle... it hasn't implemented that part of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

This can be down with [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm) syntax:

```
merge into table1 t1 
using ( 
  select field1, field2, field3, joinfield
  from table2
  where table2.field1 = 0
) merge_set
on (
  t1.joinfield = merge_set.joinfield 
)
when matched then update
  set 
    t1.field1 = merge_set.field1,
    t1.field2 = merge_set.field2,
    t1.field3 = merge_set.field3
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7785a/3)

Plus look at question at [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join) [provided by @Ben in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033229/update-multiple-field-values-based-on-join#comment24621518_17033229).