# Why does this stored procedure not work?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-update, inner-join

I'm not quite sure why this stored is not working. I am getting an message saying "pl/sql statement not properly ended".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPROVEUSER (
    seuser IN USERS_STOCK_EXCHANGES.USERNAME%TYPE,
    semanager in STOCK_EXCHANGES.STOCK_EXCHANGE_MANAGER%TYPE )
    AS 
    BEGIN
      UPDATE USERS_STOCK_EXCHANGES SET VERIFY_STATUS=1
      FROM USERS_STOCK_EXCHANGES use
        INNER JOIN
           STOCK_EXCHANGES se
        ON 
          use.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID = se.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID
      WHERE use.USERNAME = seuser
      AND  se.STOCK_EXCHANGE_MANAGER = semanager;

    END APPROVEUSER;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no joins in UPDATE statement, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2446764/1970912) and [Oracle SQL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_10008.htm#i2067715).

In your case I would write something like this

```
UPDATE users_stock_exchanges use 
SET    verify_status = 1 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   stock_exchanges se 
               WHERE  use.stock_exchange_id = se.stock_exchange_id 
                      AND use.username = seuser
                      AND se.stock_exchange_manager = semanager);
```