# Remove Duplicate Code from UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have the following query.

```
UPDATE A SET b = (SELECT b FROM B WHERE A.a_id = B.a_id AND B.value = ?)
```

This might fill A with NULL values if no a_id exists in B where value = ?. but this is okay, because before executing this query, it is certain that A.b contains only NULL values to begin with.

However, I need the number of updated columns to reflect the number of updates performed. So I changed it into this:

```
UPDATE A SET b = (SELECT b FROM B WHERE A.a_id = B.a_id AND B.value = ?)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b FROM B WHERE A.a_id = B.a_id AND B.value = ?)
```

I don't like this solution, because now I have duplicate code and have to fill the parameter multiple times. This gets even uglier when the where clause gets more complicated.

Is there a way to get rid of this duplicate code?

(BTW I'm on Oracle 10, but I prefer DB independent solutions)

Comment: Look into the `MERGE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Updat using an inner join

```
UPDATE A
INNER JOIN B ON A.a_id = B.a_id
SET A.b = B.b
WHERE B.value = ?
```

If that isn't allowed with your particular RDBMS, perhaps you could SELECT the old and new values into an aliased table expression and update using that. See [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)