# Updating issue in oracle (see description)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to oracle so don't laugh if I ask a stupid question:)
Here's my problem
Consider I have two tables
**t1**. in inserts

```
insert into `t1` (`iss_id`, `tr_type`, `perc`) values('1','26','1');
insert into `t1` (`iss_id`, `tr_type`, `perc`) values('2','26','4');
```

and **t2** in insert

```
insert into `t2` (`id`, `perc`) values('1','0');
insert into `t2` (`id`, `perc`) values('2','0');
```

(the rows in tables are much more)

I want to update t2 so that the result was like this:

```
insert into `t2` (`id`, `perc`) values('1','1');
insert into `t2` (`id`, `perc`) values('2','4');
```

How can I write a proper update for this? I tried with decode function, but the rows in tables are more than it allows.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with your update? Are you trying to update t2.perc with t1.perc where t2.id = t2.iss_id?

Comment: yes exactly, and i see the answer from your comment)))
UPDATE t2
   SET perc = (SELECT perc FROM
                  t1 WHERE t2.'id' = t1.'iss_id')
this will work for me right?

Comment: It looks Ok to me. Have you tested it?

Comment: why not insert into t2 select iss_id, perc from t1? after insert into t1, instead of insert into t2 values()

Comment: @Drumbeg right now i could do the test on MySql, it worked as needed, and i see no reasons for it not to work on Oracle. Thank you.

Comment: @Sumit to answer to your question i have to explain the whole process of my work. It just needs to be with an update like this)) thanks to you too for the response :))

Comment: Of course you would not have backticks in the Oracle SQL

Comment: @arminrock You can test whether your solution works with Oracle 11gR2 using http://sqlfiddle.com/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle)