# update set from inner join query thowing error

Tags: oracle

I want to run a query like:

```
UPDATE   I
SET I.CAP_NAME =  S.CAP_NAME 
FROM INSURED_FARMERS  I 
INNER JOIN INDIAN_STATES_REGION  S 
   ON UPPER(I.STATE_NAME_FI) = UPPER(S.STATE_NAME)
```

but it throws an error: sql error ora-00933 sql command not properly ended on line:
SET I.CAP_NAME =  S.CAP_NAME

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can write an UPDATE statement in Oracle using a JOIN.

```
UPDATE INSURED_FARMERS I
SET I.CAP_NAME = ( SELECT S.CAP_NAME 
                   FROM INDIAN_STATES_REGION  S 
                   WHERE UPPER(I.STATE_NAME_FI) = UPPER(S.STATE_NAME) )
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT S.CAP_NAME 
               FROM INDIAN_STATES_REGION  S 
               WHERE UPPER(I.STATE_NAME_FI ) = UPPER(S.STATE_NAME) )
```

Comment: Since you're faster...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60d85/1

Comment: Well pointed out @Passerby that there are two approaches to this. i.e. Dropping the `EXISTS` would result in setting `NULL` for all records without a match.

Answer (score 1):

see here: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)

you can do both ways:

1. like there is an answer with exists
2. using inline view if your tables are connected by the columns with unique indexes or primary keys (these columns `UPPER(I.STATE_NAME_FI) = UPPER(S.STATE_NAME)`)