# Update table from another table for certain fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I need you help in updating changes a table.

the table i want to update is `IP_VISIT_EASTERN_REGION`, the field I want to update is `VISIT_STAT`

so I wrote this query

```
UPDATE IP_VISIT_EASTERN_REGION SET
IP_VISIT_EASTERN_REGION.VISIT_STAT=TEST_IP_VISIT_EASTERN_REGION.VISIT_STAT
WHERE IP_VISIT_EASTERN_REGION.VISIT_ID = TEST_IP_VISIT_EASTERN_REGION.VISIT_ID
```

The Issue is I get an error

```
ORA-00904 INVALID IDENTIFIER
```

and is this the correct way to do it.

your help will be really appreciated.

thank you

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: Please do present table structure for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write an `UPDATE` from a `SELECT` by using a join. Try this approach instead.

[update set from inner join query thowing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965921/update-set-from-inner-join-query-thowing-error/20966061#20966061)

In your case:

```
UPDATE IP_VISIT_EASTERN_REGION REGION
SET REGION.VISIT_STAT= ( SELECT TEST.VISIT_STAT 
                         FROM TEST_IP_VISIT_EASTERN_REGION TEST
                         WHERE REGION.VISIT_ID = TEST.VISIT_ID )
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT TEST.VISIT_STAT 
               FROM TEST_IP_VISIT_EASTERN_REGION TEST
               WHERE REGION.VISIT_ID = TEST.VISIT_ID );
```

Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2178ae/1

Comment: Thank you but I got this error.. ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Is `VISIT_ID` not a primary key in `TEST_IP_VISIT_EASTERN_REGION`? I'd assumed it would identify a unique row in your tables? Otherwise, how do you know which record in the `TEST` table to use for your update?

Comment: I have a compound key

Comment: So, what is the key? Your `WHERE` should be based on this key.

Comment: Include all the fields of composite primary key in WHERE clause so that it will return only one row. Thanks