# Converting nested sql update query to JOIN operation

Tags: sql, oracle, join, nested

I was wondering how can I change my query to JOIN one with the same result:

```
update CDR 
set CDR_TYPE = 'ON_NET' 
where anum in (select subscriber 
               from DEGREE 
               where sub_type = 'MTN')
  and bnum in (select subscriber 
               from DEGREE 
               where sub_type = 'MTN')
```

FYI: I am using ORACLE database.

Best Regards.

Comment: Sql server or mysql or oracle ? They have different syntax gor join/ update operation

Comment: Oracle database actually.

Comment: I don't think oracle supports `join` in `update` statements.

Comment: So how can I improve the performance of my query?

Comment: You might wanna look at this answer => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join

Comment: If the below solution from m hasan doesn't work.  You could always use a WITH clause to load your subquery, then you don't have to run that query twice.

Comment: @Devon Would you please explain more?

Comment: @Alin, I added an answer below with the WITH clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a WITH clause to get rid of the repeated subquery.

```
WITH subquery AS (select subscriber 
               from DEGREE 
               where sub_type = 'MTN')
UPDATE cdr
SET cdr_type = 'ON_NET' 
WHERE anum IN (subquery)
  AND bnum IN (subquery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT cdr_type 
 FROM cdr c
 INNER JOIN degree d
 ON c.anum = d.subscriber 
    AND c.bnum = d.subscriber
 WHERE d.sub_type = 'MTN'
) t
SET t.cdr_type = 'ON_NET'
```

Comment: Just as an onlooker, that is a pretty interesting query.  Mind explaining how the subquery works in it?

Comment: It should update more than 52m records while it just update 18k of them!