# Update statement in Mysql and Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have an update statement that is working in Mysql.(update multiple records, based on the column in another table)

```
UPDATE  `table1` m 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT cse_cd FROM  table2 WHERE clsf_ind='NC') t 
ON m.cse_cd = t.cse_cd 
SET m.ST_CD = 'QUEST03'
```

However, it does not work in Oracle.
Can somebody help on  this.

Comment: The syntax differs for oracle and MySql Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET ST_CD = 'QUEST03'
WHERE EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1 
      FROM table2 
      WHERE clsf_ind='NC' AND table1.cse_cd=table2.cse_cd);
```