# Adding a column to an existing table via join - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that exists currently, and I want to add in a column from another table via a join.  Is there a way to add it to this table and not have to create a new one?  I know I could easily make another table with by joining the data in but I wasn't sure if there was a way to insert that kind of data to an existing one.

Comment: If the data already exists and the tables can be joined, what is the point of adding the data to the first table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join

Comment: Nick, the reason is for ease of using the table in another application.  It is easier to use when we have the tables built out the way we want them in oracle before importing/connecting to them.  I know in most instances it wouldn't be the best way to go but this is an unusual use.

Comment: Can you create a view for the application to use then, that does the join without exposing the complexity?