# Update Table from another Table Values return Error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have two Tables `Employee_Data` and `IOT_Codes_Temp`, I want to Update the records of `Employee_Data.IOT_Codes` with `IOT_Codes_Temp.IOT_Codes`. Below is my Query:

```
UPDATE employee_data t1 
SET    ( t1.iot_codes, t1.iot_codes_numeric ) = (SELECT t2.iot_code, 
                                                        t2.iot_code_numeric 
                                                 FROM   ot_codes_temp t2 
                                                 WHERE 
       t2.office = t1.department);
```

But it returns Error message: **ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.**
Help me how to get rid of this error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The syntax you are trying to use is of INSERT Statement .. This will do it for you ..

```
DECLARE @IOT_CODE INT;
DECLARE @IOT_CODE_NUMERIC INT;

SET @IOT_CODE=select t2.IOT_CODE From OT_CODES_TEMP t2,employee_data t1 Where t2.OFFICE=t1.DEPARTMENT;

SET @IOT_CODE_NUMERIC =select t2.IOT_CODE_NUMERIC From OT_CODES_TEMP t2,employee_data t1 Where t2.OFFICE=t1.DEPARTMENT;

update employee_data 
set 
IOT_CODES=@IOT_CODE ,
IOT_CODES_NUMERIC=@IOT_CODE_NUMERIC;
```

**EDIT**

I looked into this further .. you can also do something like this .. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2446834/1874556)

```
 UPDATE 
 (SELECT table1.value as OLD, table2.CODE as NEW
 FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2
 ON table1.value = table2.DESC
 WHERE table1.UPDATETYPE='blah'
 ) t
 SET t.OLD = t.NEW
```

Comment: OP's question is about `Oracle`, isn't it?

Comment: he has a sql tag too .. I believe oracle and sql have the same syntax .. [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj26498.html)

Answer (score -1):

The error message says it all: your "update" syntax requires one row, but your subselect is returning multiple rows.

OPTION 1: qualify your subselect so that it only returns one row

OPTION 2: change your "=" to "IN" (or "ANY", "A"" or "NOT")

It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to update multiple data with multiple rows for e.g. Information Technology has IOT_Code IT, so IT will be assign to All those employees in Employee_Data who has Department=Information Technology.