# How to update in oracle to set a constant name for resultset

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've got this code(it works):

```
update CES.SCHEME_ELEMENT se
set se.NAME = (
select ni.NAME_WT from CES.NI_CES ni
where se.FK_VALUE = ni.ID_NI_WORK and 
se.SCHEME_ID = 11 and se."TYPE" = 'zn' );
```

And don't understand, why I can't do something like this

```
update CES.NI_CES ni
set ni.NAME_WT = 'ЗР'
where ni.ID_NI_WORK = (
select se.FK_VALUE from CES.SCHEME_ELEMENT se
where  se.SCHEME_ID = 11 and se."TYPE"='zn');
```

OR

```
UPDATE
(SELECT ni.NAME_WT nw
 FROM CES.NI_CES ni
 INNER JOIN CES.SCHEME_ELEMENT se
 ON se.FK_VALUE = ni.ID_NI_WORK
 WHERE se.SCHEME_ID = 11 and se."TYPE"='zn'
) t
SET t.nw = 'ЗР';
```

Saw this [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)

Thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `in` operator instead of the `=` operator for the sub query:

```
update CES.NI_CES ni
set ni.NAME_WT = 'ЗР'
where ni.ID_NI_WORK IN ( --HERE!
select se.FK_VALUE 
from CES.SCHEME_ELEMENT se
where  se.SCHEME_ID = 11 and se."TYPE"='zn');
```