# Update not working in Oracle, 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

This doesn't work in Oracle, please help

```
update mrp_indeksy mrp
inner join indeksy i
on i.indeks_czesci=mrp.indeks_czesci 
set mrp.jest_w_raporcie_pzm='N'
where i.id_grupy='WG' and mrp.kod_uzyskania='P' and i.nazwa_czesci NOT LIKE 'ZAWI%'
```

Comment: This question has already been answered on Stack Overflow. Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join I suggest that you search on the site for related questions before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in Oracle one uses `WHERE EXISTS` for update queries of this type:

```
UPDATE mrp_indeksy mrp
   SET mrp.jest_w_raporcie_pzm='N'
 WHERE mrp.kod_uzyskania='P'
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM indeksy i
                 WHERE i.indeks_czesci = mrp.indeks_czesci
                   AND i.id_grupy='WG'
                   AND i.nazwa_czesci NOT LIKE 'ZAWI%' )
```

You can read more about how to do an update of this kind [at this page](http://www.patlaf.com/oracle-sql-update-statement-with-inner-join/). Aside from the `WHERE EXISTS` method above, you can also do an "updatable view." However, you can't combine an update with a `JOIN` and `UPDATE ... FROM` is not valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: Useful answer with link to more information!