# Update query whilst joining two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a table whilst using a join. The task is: 
Modify the database to show that Helen Partou has now learned to play the tambourine adequately.

Here is my attempt:

```
update MusicianInstrument
set instrumentName = 'Tambourine',levelOfExpertise = 'Adequate'
from MusicianInstrument  join Musician
on MusicianInstrument.musicianNo = Musician.musicianNo
where musicianName = 'Helen Partou';
```

However I keep getting an error with the FROM statement.....any help?!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle - Update statement with inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)

Comment: What error? And what happens when you try the strategy in the link; same error or different?

Comment: Should `join` be `inner join`?

Comment: You can't use `UPDATE ... FROM` in Oracle. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE MusicianInstrument mi
   SET mi.instrumentName = 'Tambourine'
     , mi.levelOfExpertise = 'Adequate'
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Musician m
                 WHERE m.musicianNo = mi.musicianNo
                   AND m.musicianName = 'Helen Partou');
```

On a side note since you're using Oracle I would recommend not using CamelCase or headlessCamelCase for object names.

Answer (score 2):

Your task is to *modify database*, so probably not only update table but also insert values if they are not already there. 
You can do this using [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606):

```
merge into MusicianInstrument i
using (select * from Musician where musicianName = 'Helen Partou') m
on (m.musicianNo = i.musicianNo 
  and i.instrumentName = 'Tambourine')
when matched then update set levelOfExpertise = 'Adequate'
when not matched then insert (i.musicianNo, i.instrumentName, i.levelOfExpertise)
   values (m.musicianNo, 'Tambourine', 'Adequate')
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this method again. However, for instance if Helen did not originally know how to play the instrument Tambourine, the merge query should only insert 1 row, but it is inserting 7 rows. I'm I making any sense?  How do I solve this?

Comment: You are right, there was a bug in lines 2-3. Please check now.