# An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I am trying to use this query to update a table wherein I am adding a new musician named Helen Partou who has recently learnt how to play the tambourine adequately. Here is the query:

```
merge into MusicianInstrument i
using Musician m
on (m.musicianNo = i.musicianNo 
and i.instrumentName = 'Tambourine'
and m.musicianName = 'Helen Partou')
when matched then update set levelOfExpertise = 'Adequate'
when not matched then insert (i.musicianNo, i.instrumentName, i.levelOfExpertise)
values (m.musicianNo, 'Tambourine', 'Adequate');
```

However, this error keeps appearing: 
An `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statement attempted to insert a `duplicate key`.

There is no existing key as the error may suggest. Here is the original insert into statements with data specific to each musician:

```
insert into MusicianInstrument(musicianNo,instrumentName,levelOfExpertise)
values('04','Saxophone','Expert');
insert into MusicianInstrument(musicianNo,instrumentName,levelOfExpertise)
values('04','Harp','Average');
```

Since the `MusicianInstrument` table does not contain any detail about Helen learning the Tambourine at an Adequate level, the merge into statement should update the table with this information.

Why am I getting this error? The `RDBMS` I am currently using is Oracle. Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you need to show us what your table definitions look like and identify what the keys are?

Comment: Move Helen Partou to line 2. There is her place. You are probably using answer from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285181/update-query-whilst-joining-two-tables), which was corrected.