# Updating one column in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I have an Oracle table which contains a column called dt_code, first_name, last_name, and user_id. I need to update dt_code with a list of codes that was given to me in an excel file. What would be the best way to update the column and maintain the relationships.

Comment: how many codes are we talking ? if just a few, Jean's answer should work well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as simple as

```
update your_table
set dt_code = new_code
where id = specific_id;
```

this won't break any relationships.

Note that Oracle allow you to import xls datas, but since I have no idea of your syntax it is hard to tell you how to do it.

If there is a lot of update to do, you should import all the datas in a temporary table, then do the update based on this table.

If you choose this option and you are not used to this kind of update statement, have a look at this thread [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join).

Comment: Well, he *could* use Excel to build the Update statements needed, then run them in SQL. Or if there is too many codes, it'll probably be easier loading the data from Excel into a temp table first, then update off that. ;) OP hasn't given us much info to work of (yet) though ..