# sql oracle update table data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got two tables: `table1` and `table2`

```
table1:

HW_SN (varchar2)         ID (number)

123ERZ123                (empty)
124NIJD11
4125ERT22
....
```

-

```
table2:

ID (number)             Name (varchar)

85442                   123ERZ123
85471                   124NIJD11
12478                   4125ERT22
...                     ...
```

`table1` has another column called `ID` which is empty.

I need to check `table1-HW_SN` if its the same to `table2-Name` - if yes it should add `table2-ID` to `table1-ID`.

Comment: without showing what you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1
SET ID = (SELECT table2.ID
                     FROM table2
                     WHERE table1.HW_SN = table2.Name)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT table2.ID
                     FROM table2
                     WHERE table1.HW_SN = table2.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks Matt - my mistake was I totally forgot about the 'WHERE EXISTS' part - helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

This is an `update` operation.  Unfortunately, Oracle does not support `join` with `update`, so you have two choices.  You can use `merge`.  Or, in this case, a subqueries accomplish what you want:

```
update table1
    set id = (select id from table2 t2 where t2.name = table1.hw_sn and rownum = 1)
    where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.name = table1.hw_sn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET id = (SELECT id FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.name = t1.hw_sn)
```

that's your homework done for you!