# populate blank columns using update statment

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help writing update statement. My objective is to populate any blank EQ_ID and ORDERID  by copying the EQ_ID and ORDERID from a row that has the same A_NUMBER, C_CD, and PERSONID

I require the update statement to scan the EST (name of the table) table:

1. For a certain period of time eg.  1st May 2015 to 10th May 2015
2. Look for a row with blank EQ_ID and ORDER_ID
3. populate any blank EQ_ID and ORDERID  by copying the EQ_ID and ORDERID of a row that has the same A_NUMBER, C_CD, and PERSONID

Can you please let me know how to do this the best way?

Attached is a screenshot of data from EST table
[image: Example table data]

Comment: MS SqL? Look for join updates

Comment: thanks for replying. but no this is Oracle SQL

Comment: include what you tried so far?

Comment: If you're using Oracle, googling "Update join" yields this as the second hit:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `update` and a correlated subquery.  Oracle allows you to set multiple columns from the same subquery:

```
update est
    set (eq_id, order_id) = (select est2.eq_id, est2.order_id
                             from est est2
                             where est2.a_number = est.a_number and
                                   est2.c_cd = est.c_cd and
                                   est2.personid = est.personid and
                                   rownum = 1
                            )
    where eq_id = 0 and orderid = 0;
```

You say "blank" in the text but the data shows `0`.  The outer `where` clause may need to be modified to suit your actual data.

Comment: thanks Gordon, this method seems easier and makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Psuedo Code:

```
Select distinct A_NUMBER, C_CD, PERSONID 
     into temp_table from TableName 
     where EQ_ID = 0 and Order_ID = 0

-- Choose correct data types
declare @Current_ANumber varchar(100)
declare @Current_C_CD varchar(100)
declare @Current_PERSONID varchar(100)
declare @Current_EQ_ID varchar(100)
declare @Current_Order_ID varchar(100)

select @Current_ANumber = A_NUMBER, @Current_C_CD= C_CD, @Current_PERSONID= PERSONID from temp_table
while (@Current_ANumber is not null)
begin
     select distinct @Current_EQ_ID = EQ_ID, @Current_Order_ID = Order_ID where EQ_ID > 0 and Order_ID > 0
     update table_name set EQ_ID = @Current_EQ_ID, Order_ID = @Current_Order_ID
          where A_NUMBER = @Current_ANumber 
               and C_CD = @Current_C_CD 
               and PERSONID = @Current_PERSONID
               and EQ_ID = 0
               and Order_ID = 0

     delete from temp_table 
          where A_NUMBER = @Current_ANumber 
               and C_CD = @Current_C_CD 
               and PERSONID = @Current_PERSONID

     set @Current_ANumber = null                   
     set @Current_C_CD = null                   
     set @Current_PERSONID= null                   
     select @Current_ANumber = A_NUMBER, @Current_C_CD= C_CD, @Current_PERSONID= PERSONID from temp_table
end
```

I work with SQL Server, so while this code may not work out of the box for Oracle, it should put you on the right path.