# Oracle SQL: Updating a data by 15%

Tags: sql, oracle, data-modeling

I am trying to update stock prices for items for which there is a 15% stock increase. Below is my code to create the tables (I have already inserted all my data):

```
CREATE TABLE Warehouse
(WarehouseID CHAR(3),
 LocationCity VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
 LocationState CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT Warehouse_WarehouseID_PK PRIMARY KEY (WarehouseID),
 CONSTRAINT Warehouse_WarehouseID_CC CHECK (UPPER(WarehouseID) IN ('MEL', 'SYD', 'BNE', 'HBA', 'ADL', 'PER', 'DIA')),
 CONSTRAINT Warehouse_LocationState_CC CHECK (UPPER(LocationState) IN ('QLD', 'NSW', 'VIC',  'TAS',  'ACT',  'SA',  'WA',  'NT'))
);

CREATE TABLE Stock
(StockNo CHAR(4),
 StockDesc VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
 UnitsOnHand NUMERIC DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
 ItemCategory CHAR(2),
 UnitCost NUMERIC(4,2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL,
 ReorderLevel NUMERIC(2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT Category_StockNo_PK PRIMARY KEY (StockNo),
 CONSTRAINT Category_ItemCategory_FK FOREIGN KEY (ItemCategory) REFERENCES "CATEGORY"(CategoryID),
 CONSTRAINT Category_StockDesc_UK UNIQUE (StockDesc),
 CONSTRAINT Category_UnitCost_CC CHECK (UnitCost BETWEEN 0.00 AND 9999.99),
 CONSTRAINT Category_ReorderLevel_CC CHECK (ReorderLevel BETWEEN -1 AND 99)
);
```

Here's the current code to update prices by 15% (separate workspace):

```
UPDATE Stock
SET Stock.UnitCost = (Stock.UnitCost * 1.15)
WHERE Warehouse.WarehouseID = 'MEL';
```

It comes up with this error:

```
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 7 Error report - SQL Error:  
ORA-00904: "WAREHOUSE"."WAREHOUSEID": invalid identifier  
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"  
*Cause:     
*Action:
```

Comment: You missed to Join `WAREHOUSE` table. What is the common column between `Stock` and `WAREHOUSE` table or How will you relate `WAREHOUSE` table with `Stock` table

Comment: Where do I insert an INNER JOIN?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join

Answer (score 3):

Currently you have no relationship between Stock and Warehouse.  Without a defined relationship you cannot update the one table using criteria from the other.

If any given item of stock is held in only one warehouse you could just add `WarehouseID` to the STOCK table. In that case your update would be this:

```
UPDATE stock s
SET s.UnitCost = (s.UnitCost * 1.15)
WHERE s.WarehouseID = 'MEL'
;
```

More likely Stock items can be held in more than one Warehouse, in which case you need a third table.  This table will store how much stock is held in each warehouse.

```
create table warehouse_stock ( 
   WarehouseID CHAR(3) not null,
   StockNo CHAR(4) not null,
   UnitsOnHand NUMERIC DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    constraint warehouse_stock_pk primary key (WarehouseID, StockNo),
    constraint warehouse_stock_warehouse_fk foreign key (WarehouseID)
        references warehouse(warehouseID),
    constraint warehouse_stock_stock_fk foreign key (StockNo)
        references stock(stockNo)
)
```

Note that you need to remove the column `UnitsOnHand` from STOCK table as it doesn't belong there.  Allocating this central amount of stock between different warehouses is left as an exercise for the reader.

Now your update will be:

```
UPDATE stock s
SET s.UnitCost = (s.UnitCost * 1.15)
WHERE s.stockno in ( select ws.stockno from Warehouse ws
                     where .ws.WarehouseID = 'MEL')
;
```