# how to match a value of table01 with a column name in table02 and update that column value sql

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a table as

```
table01 (rollno, etcs100, etcs101, etcs102)
table02 (serialno, subjectcode)
```

I want to select a value from `table02` (ie. subjectcode = "etcs100" )
and match this value from Column Name of `table01` and update this column value by 1.

```
UPDATE TABLE01
SET (SELECT SUBJECTCODE 
     FROM table02 WHERE SERIALNUMBER = '1') 
         = (SELECT SUBJECTCODE FROM table02 
             WHERE SERIALNUMBER = '1') + 1
WHERE rollno = 1
```

We are looking for a query like this.
we are using oracle database

Comment: what db are you using mysql or oracle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle - Update statement with inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)

Comment: @Mureinik - this question is *not* a duplicate of that question.  The second table is a metadata table, which provides the column name to be used in the update.  So, not a join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL for this.  The syntax varies according to database flavour.  Here is the syntax for Oracle.

```
declare
    l_col_name varchar2(30);
begin
    SELECT SUBJECTCODE 
    into l_col_name
    FROM table02 
    WHERE SERIALNUMBER = '1';

    execute immediate
        'UPDATE TABLE01 SET '|| l_col_name || ' = '
              || l_col_name || ' + 1 WHERE rollno = 1'
    ;
end;
```

MySQL offers similar functionality with prepared statements.  [Find out more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).