# Identify phone numbers in a PL/SQL iteration

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to update a table (T_NUMBERS) which has a PHONE_NUMBER and a COUNTRY columns. The COUNTY col is empty (all NULL), The phone numbers are not unique and their format: "420575757111" (starts with the country code without + or 00). The international calling codes are stored in another table (INT_CODES), two columns: INT_CODE, COUNTRY. Looks like this:

```
COUNTRY     ||   INT_CODE
-------------------------
USA/CANADA  ||  1
RUSSIA      ||  7
EGYPT       ||  20
GREECE      ||  30
BELGIUM     ||  32
FRANCE      ||  33
HUNGARY     ||  36
COLOMBIA    ||  57
KENYA       ||  254
IRELAND     ||  353
GRENADA     ||  1473
```

and so on.

My concept is to create a script which works in the following way:

- In the first round compares the first 4 digits of the phone numbers to INT_CODE and update the T_NUMBERS.COUNTRY fields with INT_CODES.COUNTRY where it founds a match, something like this:

  ```
  INT_CODES.INT_CODE = SUBSTR(T_NUMBERS.PHONE_NUMBER,1,4)
  ```
- thereafter the second round compares the first 3 digits  where the T_NUMBERS.COUNTRY is still NULL.
- in the next two rounds check the 2 and the 1 digit codes in the same way in order to fill the all country field but to not override the already filled ones.

My problem is I couldn't run a single script which would execute at least the first step because Oracle seemingly does not support the JOIN in UPDATE statements as you can read here for example:

[Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)

and I tried the solutions from the answer, but it doesn't work:

*SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row*

After that I tried this (only the first round):

```
begin
for t_rows in c_code
loop

    update (select TN.COUNTRY as C_OLD, IC.COUNTRY as C_NEW from T_NUMBERS TN
    left join INT_CODES IC on IC.INT_CODE = substr(TN.PHONE_NUMBER,1,4) where
    TN.COUNTRY IS NULL) T_TAB

    set TAB.C_OLD = TAB.C_NEW;
close c_code;

end loop;
```

Error message:
*ORA-06512: at line 8
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"*

So my main question is: what statement I should insert into a loop?
My side-question: Is there any other solution to produce the same result (without creating further tables or modifying the structure of the existing ones)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say its quite hard to find another sql-engine more feature rich then oracle.
I advice you to setup [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for question like this.

```
UPDATE t_numbers tn SET
  tn.country = (
    SELECT ic.country 
    FROM int_codes ic 
    WHERE ic.int_code = substr(tn.phone_number, 1, 4)
  )
WHERE tn.country IS NULL;
```

if you running it as pl/sql script you can wrap it with loop, to avoid copy/paste.

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN REVERSE 1..4
  LOOP
    UPDATE t_numbers tn SET
      tn.country = (
        SELECT ic.country 
        FROM int_codes ic 
        WHERE ic.int_code = substr(tn.phone_number, 1, i)
      )
    WHERE tn.country IS NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This code relies on a fact that column `int_code` in the `int_codes` table is UK.

Comment: See my reaction under San's answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. I'll update answer to reflect this problem too.

Answer (score 2):

What is the need of a loop here? You have to re-write your update statement to something like this:

```
UPDATE t_numbers tn
   SET tn.country = (SELECT ic.country
                       FROM int_codes ic
                      WHERE ic.int_code = substr(tn.phone_number, 1, 4))
 WHERE tn.country is null
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM int_codes ic
                WHERE ic.int_code = substr(tn.phone_number, 1, 4));
```

Then repeat the same for 3, 2, and 1 as follows(for 3):

```
UPDATE t_numbers tn
   SET tn.country = (SELECT ic.country
                       FROM int_codes ic
                      WHERE ic.int_code = substr(tn.phone_number, 1, 3))
 WHERE tn.country is null
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM int_codes ic
                WHERE ic.int_code = substr(tn.phone_number, 1, 3));
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also loop through 4 to 1 to achieve the task

```
  begin
    for i in 1..4 loop
      UPDATE t_numbers tn
       SET tn.country = (SELECT ic.country
                           FROM int_codes ic
                          WHERE ic.int_code = substr(tn.phone_number, 1, (5-i)))
     WHERE tn.country is null
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM int_codes ic
                    WHERE ic.int_code = substr(tn.phone_number, 1, (5-i)));
    end loop;
  END;
```

Comment: I tried both solutions above, but the error message is still the same:

Comment: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: That means there are multiple entries in int_codes table for a given int_code. check that and filter the data according to it. You may need to put more condition in inner sub query's where condition.

Comment: Ok, both worked fine, you were right, the problem were the call codes belonged to two different countries. I accepted Nagh's version finally, because it was more convenient, but I liked yours as well. Thank you guys!