# How to Update on table with another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables table_A and Table_B

Table_A

```
ID    Col1    Col2   Col3
123    2      A      JIM
456    2      A      JACK
```

Table_B

```
ID    Col1    Col2   Col3
123    1       B      KIM
456    1       B      LEE
```

Query Using:

```
Update Table_A a, Table_B b
Set  a.Col1 = b.Col1,
     a.Col2 = b.Col2,
     a.Col3 = b.Col3
where a.ID = b.ID
```

Current Results:
Getting error

Required Results:

I want to update value of Table 1 with value of Table 2.

Comment: You've tagged this for Oracle and MySQL.  Which database are you actually using?

Comment: Sorry for Oracle Databse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
Update
(
    Select  a.Col1, a.Col2, a.Col3,
            b.Col1 As New_Col1, 
            b.Col2 As New_Col2, 
            b.Col3 As New_Col3
    From    Table_A     a
    Join    Table_B     b   On  a.ID = b.ID
) ToUpdate
Set ToUpdate.Col1 = ToUpdate.New_Col1,
    ToUpdate.Col2 = ToUpdate.New_Col2,
    ToUpdate.Col3 = ToUpdate.New_Col3
```

Reference: [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)

Comment: Not working....giving following error  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @Qasim0787 Updated query

Comment: Thanks Perfect working fine