# Update Value Based On Value In Another Table

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: Tables Involved]I am looking to modify the value of a column on one table based on the condition of the value of a column of another table.

I am using the code:

```
UPDATE ORDERDETAIL
SET ORDERDETAIL.PRODUCTID = 'BASE1'
WHERE CUSTOMER.FIRSTNAME = 'JANE' AND CUSTOMER.LASTNAME = 'DOE';
```

This should be very straightforward, where am I going wrong?

Comment: are you able to run this without getting any errors? Apart from that, Looks like you are missing join between order detail and customer.Do u have any customer Id column in order details table?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the second TABLE explicitly. Join should work. Remember to always denote the alias rather than the table name right next to UPDATE

```
UPDATE O_T
SET PRODUCTID = 'BASE1'
from ORDERDETAIL O_T
JOIN CUSTOMER C_T
ON O_T.SOME_COLUMN_NAME=C_T.SOME_COLUMN_NAME
WHERE C_T.FIRSTNAME = 'JANE' AND C_T.LASTNAME = 'DOE';
```

Comment: Still Errors:
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
UPDATE O_T
SET PRODUCTID = 'BASE1'
from ORDERDETAIL O_T
JOIN CUSTOMER C_T
ON O_T.SOME_COLUMN_NAME=C_T.SOME_COLUMN_NAME
WHERE C_T.FIRSTNAME = 'JANE' AND C_T.LASTNAME = 'DOE'
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: ON O_T.SOME_COLUMN_NAME=C_T.SOME_COLUMN_NAME

You got to change the "SOME_COLUMN_NAME" to the respective column in your table. I have given SOME_COLUMN_NAME because I cannot see your table structure.

Comment: Yes, I did correct that code:

UPDATE O_T
SET PRODUCTID = 'BASE1'
FROM ORDERDETAIL O_T
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C_T
ON O_T.PRODUCTID=C_T.CUSTOMERID
WHERE C_T.FIRSTNAME = 'JANE' AND C_T.LASTNAME = 'DOE';

But it still fails. Am I missing your point somewhere? I'm sorry.

Comment: Can you post the error here? A screenshot with your table structure and error would help too

Comment: Evil333 it still errors out: Error starting at line : 1 in command -
UPDATE O_T
SET PRODUCTID = 'BASE1'
from ORDERDETAIL O_T
JOIN CUSTOMER C_T
ON O_T.SOME_COLUMN_NAME=C_T.SOME_COLUMN_NAME
WHERE C_T.FIRSTNAME = 'JANE' AND C_T.LASTNAME = 'DOE'
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: This approach is not valid in Oracle, [which does not let you have a join in the update statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10008.htm#i2112182).

Answer (score 0):

If you are always using a fixed value, you an use `exists` to find records which match the condition in the other tables:

```
UPDATE ORDERDETAIL OD
SET OD.PRODUCTID = 'BASE1'
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM CUSTOMER C
  JOIN ORDERS O ON O.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID
  WHERE C.FIRSTNAME = 'JANE'
  AND C.LASTNAME = 'DOE'
  AND O.ORDERID = OD.ORDERID
);
```

Or a subquery:

```
UPDATE ORDERDETAIL OD
SET OD.PRODUCTID = 'BASE1'
WHERE OD.ORDERID IN (
  SELECT O.ORDERID
  FROM CUSTOMER C
  JOIN ORDERS O ON O.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID
  WHERE C.FIRSTNAME = 'JANE'
  AND C.LASTNAME = 'DOE'
);
```

Oracle [doesn't allow you](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10008.htm#i2112182) to have a join directly in the update statement. If you were getting the new value from the other table as well you would [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2446764/266304).