# Update Table in Oracle with value from another table with a specific condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in Oracle 11:

**Table ta_one:**

```
name    | active
----------------
john    | yes
tina    | yes
mike    | yes
```

**Table ta_two:**

```
name    | active
----------------
john    | yes
tina    | yes
tina    | no
mike    | no
```

The goal I want to achieve is the following:
I want to update the column "active" in the first table ta_one with the value of the column "active" from the second table ta_two under the following conditions:

- the name in column "name" in ta_one matches the "name" in ta_two (e.g.: mike and mike)
- if there is more than one entry of the same name in ta_two, no update should happen (e.g.: tina)
- if there is not a "no" in the column active in table ta_two, no update should happen (e.g.: john)

So the table ta_one should look like this after the update:

```
name    | active
----------------
john    | yes
tina    | yes
mike    | no
```

Only mike's entry has changed, because tina is more than one time in the second table and johns entry has a 'yes' in the active column of table ta_two.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have an update-join syntax, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2446764/2422776), although not an exact duplicate, may give you some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with always updating with the value `'yes'` because your logic will only be doing this.

```
UPDATE ta_one
SET active = 'no'
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT t2.active
    FROM ta_one t1
    INNER JOIN ta_two t2
        ON t1.name = t2.name
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT name
        FROM ta_two
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) t3
        ON t1.name = t3.name
    WHERE t2.active = 'no' AND
          ta_one.name = t1.name
);
```

Comment: You seem to missing a `where` clause. What if the query inside the `set` clause doesn't return a row? IIUC, this will error out.

Comment: I have tried it out and it does update 3 rows. The first table ta_one has active = yes at john and an empty value on the other two entries. I think Mureinik is right with his comment. @TimBiegeleisen Ah i see, wil try it.

Comment: @Gletschernadel I updated again, try reloading your page.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If I run it, i get 1 updated row, but the table does not change. If I change your 2 `yes` into a `no` it seems to work.

Comment: But changing both to `no` would seem to contradict your logic.  Are you sure you worded your question correctly?

Comment: Based on what I read, an update should only happen if `ta_two` contains `yes` for its active value.

Comment: Hmm english is not my native language so its possible. (: I want the "no" from the second table into the first one (following the conditions above)

Comment: If you want to update with `no` values whenever they occur in `ta_two` (along with your other criteria), then my updated query might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the following will fit:

```
update 
  ta_one o 
set 
  o.active='no' 
where o.name in (select name from ta_two where active='no') 
and (select count(*) from ta_two where name=o.name)=1
```

Comment: You may replace o.active='no'  with  o.active=(select active from ta_two where name=o.name), but in this case it's the same.
If you do so, there is just one place to edit the value from 'no' to another value (if you have other examples)

Answer (score 0):

```
update ta_one
   set active =
       (select active from ta_two where ta_one.name = ta_two.name)
 where 1 = (select count(1)
              from ta_two
             where ta_two.name = ta_one.name
             group by name)
```

Answer (score 0):

update ta_one x
set active=( select  y.active
             from    ta_two y
             where   y.name=x.name
            )
where not exists  (
 select  1
             from    ta_two y
             where   y.name=x.name
             group by name
             having count(distinct y.active) > 1
)