# How to join table and get values

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables:

`LOGS_TABLE`:

```
FID           (NUMBER)
SERIAL_NUMBER (VARCHAR2)
LOG_RESULT    (VARCHAR2)
```

`POINT_TABLE`:

```
FID           (NUMBER)
SERIAL_NUMBER (VARCHAR2)
FID_LOG       (NUMBER)
```

The attribute to join tables is `SERIAL_NUMBER`, but what I need is to insert into `POINT_TABLE.FID_LOG` values from `LOGS_TABLE.FID` on basement `SERIAL_NUMBER` relations.

How can I do this?

Comment: The question is unclear, at least to me. Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle you may use following statement:

```
UPDATE (SELECT p.FID_LOG fid_log
             , l.FID     fid
          FROM POINT_TABLE p
             , LOGS_TABLE  l
         WHERE p.SERIAL_NUMBER = l.SERIAL_NUMBER)
   SET fid_log = fid
```

Also it is possible to use `MERGE` statement like this:

```
 MERGE INTO POINT_TABLE p
 USING (SELECT * 
          FROM LOGS_TABLE) l
    ON (p.SERIAL_NUMBER = l.SERIAL_NUMBER)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE 
   SET p.FID_LOG = l.FID;
```

Comment: I dont know why, but it shows me followinf error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" for LOGS TABLE.... Its interesting, because I can see LOGS TABLE in database content...

Comment: I have updated query. May be this is because of alias names. Also, please, try to use table name with schema prefix, like this: "schema"."table"
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm