# SQL command not properly ended : Update SET FROM JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try to execute the script below on sql developer I've got this exception :

> 933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

```
UPDATE T1 SET T1.IDC= T2.IDC
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON (T1.IDC=T2.IDO);
```

I don't get what's wrong with my script.
Can Anyone help please?

Comment: This syntax works in `SQL Server` not in `Oracle`

Comment: Check this question for various ways to achieve this [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Comment: @AjGupta - Question is tagged with `ORACLE` it is a very popular `RDBMS`

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find that syntax?

Comment: Welcome to S.O.  Please take a minute to search the archives before posting. You will often find questions about a specific error message were already asked an answered.  Voting to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you do not have the JOIN clause in the UPDATE statement. You can use the following:
    `UPDATE T1
    SET T1.IDC = (SELECT T2.IDC from T2 WHERE T2.IDO = T1.IDC)`
Add the WHERE clause if you do not want to update the entire table.