# How Update Statement using Derived Table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

UPDATE Actual
     SET    Actual.tranamt=ABS(Actual.tranamt-Reversal.tranamt),
         Actual.tranamt_org  =  ABS(Actual.tranamt),
            Actual.trans_flag = 'U'
     FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM   "MATCHPOINT_DEV"."GTT_temp_raw_neft_cbs_iss"
     )  AS Actual
     INNER JOIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM   "MATCHPOINT_DEV"."GTT_temp_raw_neft_cbs_iss"  WHERE (reversalrrn IS NOT NULL OR reversalrrn <> '')
     )  AS Reversal
     ON     Actual.rrn = Reversal.reversalrrn ;

Getting error

SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Does Oracle really support that non-standard UPDATE FROM syntax?

Comment: That's not valid syntax for Oracle. Instead, you should look at doing the update in a MERGE statement.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `merge`.  Another method, subqueries:

```
UPDATE "MATCHPOINT_DEV"."GTT_temp_raw_neft_cbs_iss" Actual                                   
    SET tranamt = 
         (SELECT ABS(Actual.tranamt - x.tranamt),                        
          FROM "MATCHPOINT_DEV"."GTT_temp_raw_neft_cbs_iss" reversal
          WHERE (reversal.reversalrrn IS NOT NULL OR reversal.reversalrrn <> '') and
                Actual.rrn = Reversal.reversalrrn 
         ),                       
       tranamt_org  =  ABS(Actual.tranamt),                                
       trans_flag = 'U'                          
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM "MATCHPOINT_DEV"."GTT_temp_raw_neft_cbs_iss" reversal
              WHERE (reversal.reversalrrn IS NOT NULL OR reversal.reversalrrn <> '') and
                    Actual.rrn = Reversal.reversalrrn 
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support that query
You can try the following format in this thread [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle)