# how to add a inner join clause in a update statement

Tags: oracle, inner-join

when i run the following query with an inner join it gives me the following error

`"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"` in my from clause.Am i not positioning it in the correct format?

```
update
             Table t

    set
         t.gross =4000
 FROM Schema1.Table  t INNER JOIN schema2.TYPES AS gt ON t.GRADE=gt.DESCRIPTION
    where
       GT.GRADE_TYPE_CODE='test'
```

Comment: From the Documentation area of SO (since it's a frequent question that confuses many, including many experts): http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/8061/update-with-joins#t=201701061428442118327

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is already on stackoverflow.

This can help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2446834/6517368

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE         TABLE t
    set          t.gross =4000
  where  t.GRADE in (   select gt.DESCRIPTION from  schema2.TYPES gt where
       GT.GRADE_TYPE_CODE='test')
```