# How to update a table with joining two other tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

We have three tables here, Session table which is connected to Green_fact table with Session_id field. Time_session table is the third table which is made of SessionDate from Session table with a primary key for every single day.

[image: all tables]

How can I populate the Date_ID field in Green_fact table.
the code below is what I think use, but it doesn't work properly

```
update green_fact 
   inner join "SESSION" on green_fact."SESSION_ID" = "SESSION"."SessionID"
   inner join "TIME_SESSION" on "TIME_SESSION"."SESSION_DATE" = "SESSION"."SessionDate"
   set green_fact."DATE_ID" = "TIME_SESSION"."ID" where green_fact."SESSION_ID" = "SESSION"."SessionID";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle)

Comment: Just a side note: You shouldn't store data redundantly. But well, maybe you are going to remove `session_date` from `session` after the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle doesn't allow `join` in `update`.  You can use correlated subqueries:

```
update green_fact gf 
   set DATE_ID = (select ts.ID
                  from SESSION s join
                       TIME_SESSION ts
                       on ts.SESSION_DATE = s.SessionDate
                  where gf.SESSION_ID = s.SESSIONID
                 )
   where exists (select ts.ID
                 from SESSION s join
                      TIME_SESSION ts
                      on ts.SESSION_DATE = s.SessionDate
                 where gf.SESSION_ID = s.SESSIONID
                );
```

The `exists` may not be necessary, if all the rows match.

Comment: Linnof can you help me with this one ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2GaZ.png  it is the same but with one less table

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you can either update a table or an updatetable query, i.e. `UPDATE tablename SET ...` or `UPDATE (SELECT ... FROM ...) SET ...`.

```
update 
(
  select gf.date_id, time_session.id as time_session_id
  from green_fact gf
  inner join session s on gf.session_id = s.sessionid 
  inner join time_session ts on ts.session_date = s.sessiondate 
)
set date_id = time_session_id;
```

This will work, provided the DBMS sees it guaranteed that the query produces one row only per green_fact record (which it should, because of the primary and foreign keys).

Answer (score 1):

Use below query for update from two tables :

```
UPDATE green_fact SET green_fact."DATE_ID" = A.Id
FROM
(
    SELECT "TIME_SESSION"."ID" Id ,  "SESSION"."SessionID" SessionID
    FROM "TIME_SESSION" 
    JOIN "SESSION" ON  "TIME_SESSION"."SESSION_DATE" =      
    "SESSION"."SessionDate"
) A
WHERE green_fact."SESSION_ID" = A.SessionID;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, why do I get this error ? "SQL command not properly ended" I think some thing is missing before "FROM".

Comment: @andrew,Check your query,any parenthesis or any alias name is missing..?

Comment: Are you sure this is valid in Oracle? I doubt that `UPDATE ... FROM` is allowed. Syntax here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708

Comment: `FROM` is not allowed in an UPDATE statement in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't allow joins to be used in `UPDATE` statements, but sometimes one can rewrite such a statement as a `MERGE` (you don't specify the version of Oracle you're using, but since 10g one can omit the `WHEN MATCHED` or `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clauses of the `MERGE`):

```
MERGE INTO green_fact gf
USING (
    SELECT s."SessionID", ts.session_date, ts.id
      FROM session s INNER JOIN time_session ts
        ON s."SessionDate" = ts.session_date ) ts1
   ON ( gf.session_id = ts1."SessionID" )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET gf.date_id = ts1.id;
```

Hope this helps.

By the way, I cannot stress enough that mixed-case object names in Oracle are a bad idea. But maybe you're dealing with legacy data and don't have a choice.