# How does update join on work in sql

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

I know how to use `join` in sql to combine two tables, here is an example: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Today I read this: https://www.javatpoint.com/sql-update-with-join

I can't understand how `update` + `join` works. Can someone explain this to me with enough details?

Comment: That's not standard ANSI SQL. Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: @Jarlh   If I want to use ANSI SQL, what kind of sql query should be used to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know what it does then what is the point of asking how to do whatever that is in standard sql? Tell us what DMBS/SQL you are using and we can tell you what its syntax means. After you have read the documentation and googled, if you are still stuck.

That site doesn't mention a DBMS/SQL for that syntax. (Both it and w3schools are poorly written resources which you should not use.) But it seems to give info only on MySQL & Oracle. The *first hits* from google 'mysql update join' & 'oracle update join' explain the MySQL update join syntax and tell you that [Oracle doesn't have it and how to do the same thing in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle).

> ```
> UPDATE table1
> INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.value = table2.DESC
> SET table1.value = table2.CODE
> WHERE table1.UPDATETYPE='blah';
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE 
> (SELECT table1.value as OLD, table2.CODE as NEW
>  FROM table1
>  INNER JOIN table2
>  ON table1.value = table2.DESC
>  WHERE table1.UPDATETYPE='blah'
> ) t
> SET t.OLD = t.NEW
> ```