# Update multiple rows with data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to update 700 rows on a table. Is it possible to do it with only one query?

2 examples:

```
UPDATE PERSON p SET p.admin = (select usr.iqid from USER usr where usr.userid = 'J072') where upper(person.myid) = '18349';

UPDATE PERSON p SET p.admin = (select usr.iqid from USER usr where usr.userid = 'PU96') where upper(person.myid) = '36895';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle)

Comment: Please provide more details , Is there a way to join the two tables ? Can you specify the DDL of two tables with the joining logic ?

Comment: sorry..Yes it's possible to join the 2 tables person.admin=user.iqid

Comment: Have you tried using `MERGE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
UPDATE PERSON p
    SET p.admin = (SELECT u.iqid 
                   FROM USER u
                   WHERE (u.userid = 'J072' AND p.myid = '18349') OR
                         (u.userid = 'PU96' AND p.myid = '36895')
                  )
    WHERE p.myid IN ('18349', '36895');
```

Notes that `upper()` is not needed for numbers.  It would generally impede the use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1.

```
update person p
   set p.admin      =
          (select usr.iqid
             from user usr
            where usr.userid = decode(upper(person.myid),  '36895', 'PU96',  '18349', 'J072'))
 where upper(person.myid) = any ('36895', '18349');
```

Option 2.
Use merge statement to avoid correlated scalar subquery.

Option 3.
`Update (select ... from person join user) set ...` if person has foreign key references user.
Google "key preserned view".