# How do i use UPDATE and JOIN in SQL oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

i have 2 tables fooditem and food_serve .i can view the data i want to change with

```
SELECT food_serve.food_serve_cost
FROM fooditem INNER JOIN food_serve
ON fooditem.food_item_no= food_serve.food_item_no and fooditem.food_type = 'M'and food_serve.food_serve_size = 'ST';
```

But im trying to update the values like this however its throwing errors at me

```
update q
set q.food_serve_cost = q.food_serve_cost *1.15
from food_serve q
inner join fooditem a
on q.food_item_no = a.food_item_no
where a.food_type = 'M' AND q.FOOD_SERVE_SIZE = 'ST';
```

after research i found that from cant be used in update but i cant find a fix for this
Any help please? im using oracle sql developer

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle

Comment: Even more duplicates here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+update+with+join

Answer (score 0):

```
update food_serve q
inner join fooditem a
on q.food_item_no = a.food_item_no
set q.food_serve_cost = q.food_serve_cost *1.15
where a.food_type = 'M' AND q.FOOD_SERVE_SIZE = 'ST';
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE ... FROM ...` syntax is coming from [PostgreSQL Update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html).

This is proprietary syntax and doesn't work on other RDBMS systems.

---

Use this query

```
update q
set q.food_serve_cost = q.food_serve_cost *1.15
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT null FROM fooditem a
  WHERE q.food_item_no = a.food_item_no
    AND a.food_type = 'M'
)
AND q.FOOD_SERVE_SIZE = 'ST'
```

or it's variation:

```
update q
set q.food_serve_cost = q.food_serve_cost *1.15
WHERE food_item_no IN (
        SELECT food_item_no  FROM fooditem 
        WHERE food_type = 'M'
     )
 AND FOOD_SERVE_SIZE = 'ST'
```