# How to update records at column levels

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

In both SQL and T-SQL, I have updated the records based on the below query:

```
Update Tablename1
SET  COlumn name : 
FROM Tablename1  one 
JOIN Tablename2  two
 ON one.PDPD_ID = two.PDPD_ID
AND one.TYPE =  two.TYPE
```

But, In Oracle I am unable to execute the query.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2446834/18747

Comment: Also, Why the update operation in Oracle override the other rows which it doesn't affects.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
UPDATE tablename1 one
   SET one.column_name =
          (SELECT two.some_column
             FROM tablename2 two
            WHERE t2.popd_id = t1.popd_id AND two.TYPE = one.TYPE);
```