# Update values in one table with values in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have `table1` and `table2`. They have the same columns and the column `ID` is the one that i can use to connect the tables.

How can i run foreach statment that will update row `Name` in `table1` with the value for column `Name` in `table2`?
I need this so i can fix the column `Name` in `Table1` because it is incorect , and the good values for it are in `table2`

I tried using a single update statement but it takes forever to execute because both tables are with over 600 000 rows

```
 update 
  table1 t1
set
  (
    t1.name
      ) = (
    select
      t2.name
    from
      table2  t2
    where
      t2.id = t1.id
    and
      rownum = 1    
     )
    where exists (
      select 
        null
      from 
        table2 t2
      where 
        t2.id = t1.id
      );
```

Comment: What have you tried so far????

Comment: I tried using one single update, but these tables are with over 600000rows and it takes forever to execute
 update 
  table1 t1
set
  (
    t1.name
      ) = (
    select
      t2.name
    from
      table2  t2
    where
      t2.id = t1.id
    and
      rownum = 1    
     )
    where exists (
      select 
        null
      from 
        table2 t2
      where 
        t2.id = t1.id
      );

Comment: Not as a comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: I think you should google a tutorial

Comment: Have you tried Google???  This link is the first result that came out in Google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
update table1 t1
    set t1.name = (select t2.name from table2  t2 where t2.id = t1.id and  rownum = 1)
    where exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id
                 );
```

You want an index on `table2(id, name)`.

Answer (score -1):

A simple inner join should work this.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.NAME = T2.NAME 
FROM MyTable T1
INNER JOIN MyOtherTable T2 
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```