# SQL insert data with inner join using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, inner-join

New to SQL I have two tables `table_A` and `table_B`.

I want to add data into a specific column of `table_A` depending on a `inner join` on `table_B`. I am using Oracle, following this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle) my SQL looks like this :

I first tried that :

```
INSERT INTO table_A (target_column)
SELECT table_B.wanted_data 
FROM table_B INNER JOIN table_A ON table_B.someColumnB = table_A.someColumnA
```

Here the issue is that it would insert the data in new lines of my `table_A` and not in the existing lines.

So I tried that from the stackoverflow thread :

```
UPDATE(SELECT table_A.target_column, table_B.wanted_data
  FROM table_A
  INNER JOIN table_B
  ON table_A.someColumnA = table_B.someColumnB
)
SET table_A.target_table = table_B.wanted_data
```

But it is not working either "SQL command not properly ended"

**EDIT :** `target_column` and `wanted_data` have the same name in my data set, not sure if it changes anything.

Comment: Did you actually miss to check that the SET statement should be `table_A.UsineId` instead of `table_A_UsineId`  in your main query?

Comment: @KaushikNayak miss from me i'll correct it

Comment: Have you gone through that  thread completely and tried all alternatives?For eg: You may also use `MERGE INTO` . I think you have probably made a mistake while copying and modifying your query.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Didn't try MERGE, gonna try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Sever:

```
UPDATE a 
SET    a.target_column = b.wanted_data 
FROM   table_A a 
JOIN   table_B b 
ON     b.someColumnB = a.someColumnA
```

Oracle:

```
UPDATE
(
    SELECT     b.wanted_data   AS wanted_data
              ,a.target_column AS old_data
    FROM       table_A a
    INNER JOIN table_B b
    ON         b.someColumnB = a.someColumnA
)   c
SET c.old_data = c.wanted_data
```

Comment: It seems that you can't update & join like that using Oracle

Comment: @LoganWlv Ah sorry missed that it was Oracle, I have updated my answer.

Comment: it seems I have an issue "column ambiguously defined", I think it's due to the same name from my target_column and wanted_data , check my last edit

Comment: @LoganWlv ah okay give the selections aliases so something like SELECT b.wanted_data AS wanted_data, a.target_column AS old_data....... SET c.old_data = c.wanted_data, I'll edit my answer again.

Comment: @LoganWlv you're missing a name for the selection. "SQL command not properly ended" note the 'c' in my code at the end of my SELECT.

Comment: Ok i will try it

Comment: Ok I have an other issue "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table" but the request is working so I will validate your answer and searching to resolve this other issue, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this approach, which you said fails with "SQL command not properly ended":

(This is the failing code:)

```
update
   ( select table_a.target_column
          , table_b.wanted_data
     from   table_a
            join table_b
                 on  table_b.somecolumnb = table_a.somecolumna
    )
set table_a.usineid = table_b.usineid;
```

I can't see why you would get that error, but the last line is incorrect because labels `table_a` and `table_b` only exist inside the inline view, which is anonymous. (Also there is no `UsineId` but I am assuming that is a copy-paste issue in your example.) It needs to be either:

```
update
   ( select table_a.target_column
          , table_b.wanted_data
     from   table_a
            join table_b
                 on  table_b.somecolumnb = table_a.somecolumna
    )  -- you are updating an anonymous inline view
set target_column = wanted_data;
```

or

```
update
   ( select table_a.target_column
          , table_b.wanted_data
     from   table_a
            join table_b
                 on  table_b.somecolumnb = table_a.somecolumna
    ) v  -- you are updating an inline view named V
set v.target_column = v.wanted_data;
```

Then, there needs to be a unique index or constraint on the parent key, `table_b.somecolumnb`, otherwise Oracle will refuse to attempt any update with

> ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Alternatively, you can use `merge`:

```
merge into table_a a
using table_b b
      on (b.somecolumnb = a.somecolumna)
when matched then update set a.target_column = b.wanted_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
update  table_A A
set     A.target_column = (
        select table_B_data 
        from   table_B 
        where  shared_key = A.shared_key
        );
```

This will only work if there is one row with table_B_date in table_B. If there are multiple rows, you need to specify the key