# ORACLE UPDATE WITH INNER JOIN ON MULTIPLE ROWS

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

I need to update table AGENT without primary key and unique rows, by the another talbe (select) AGENT_BOSS

Someting like that in MSSQL:

```
UPDATE AG
SET AGENT_BOSS_ID = AGB.AGENT_BOSS_ID
FROM AGENT AG
INNER JOIN AGENT_BOSS AGB ON (AG.AGENT_ID = AGB.AGENT_ID =)
```

NOTE:
AGENT_ID is not UNIQUE  in table AGENT

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+sql-update+join)

Comment: This is a more precise [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle)

Comment: Important requirement is, that `AGENT_BOSS.AGENT_ID` is backed by a unique index.